# PHP CSV looping through same column name

Tags: php, csv

The code below works flawlessly, except it will only post the first image that contains `main_`. I need it to pick up any column value that contains the words "main_' thus giving me the ability to post multiple images. So if I have 3 or more `main_img_url`, the loop should know this and add them accordingly. I noted below where the image handler starts and ends.

Here is an example CSV:

```
post_title, post_content, main_img_url, main_img_url
```

Here is my code:

```
function app_csv_to_array($file = '', $delimiter = ',') {
    if(!file_exists($file) || !is_readable($file))
        return false;
    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if(false !== $handle = fopen($file, 'r')) {
        while(false !== $row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) {

            if($header)
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            else
                $header = $row;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}


    function process($file) {
        $rows = $this->app_csv_to_array($file);
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $post['post_title'] = sanitize_text_field($row['post_title']);
            $post['post_content'] = sanitize_text_field($row['post_content']);
            $post['post_status'] = 'publish';
            $post['post_author'] = 658;

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
        //////////////// I want the loop to start here   //////////////////
            foreach($row as $key => $val) {
              if(strstr($key, 'main_')) {
                $tmp = download_url( $file );
                preg_match('/[^\?]+\.(jpg|JPG|jpe|JPE|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|png|PNG)/', $file, $matches);
                $filename = strtolower(basename($matches[0]));
                  } 
            }
//////////////// ends here   //////////////////
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the implementation of `app_csv_to_array` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is inside `app_csv_to_array` method and specifically in the `array_combine`.

Based on the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) `array_combine` will create one associative array from two input arrays having the values from the first for its keys and the values from the second for its values

As your keys are the headers of the `csv` file:

```
post_title, post_content, main_img_url, main_img_url
```

the resulting array that will eventually be returned will have only one slot for  `main_img_url` as its key.

On way to circumvent this problem is to make sure that your headers in the csv file are unique, allowing at the same time the `strstr($key, 'main_')` to match your columns content. Something like:

```
post_title, post_content, main_img_url1, main_img_url2
```

Comment: Wow, it was that simple? lol I changed one of the column headers as you described and it worked perfectly! I LOVE STACKOVERFLOW.COM!